# Numpy - How to shift values at indexes where change happened

Tags: python, numpy

So I would like to shift my values in a 1D numpy arrays, where change happened. The sample of shifting shall be configured.

```
input = np.array([0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0])
shiftSize = 2
out = np.magic(input, shiftSize)
print out
np.array([0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0])
```

For example the first switch happened and index 4, so index 2,3 becomes '1'.
The next happened at 5, so 6 and 7 becomes '1'.

EDIT: Also it would be important to be without for cycle because, that might be slow (it is needed for large data sets)
EDIT2: indexes and variable name

I tried with np.diff, so i get where the changes happened and then np.put, but with multiple index ranges it seems impossible.

Thank you for the help in advance!

Comment: `in` is not a valid variable name and there is no `magic` in numpy.

Comment: Index `2,3`, or indices `2` and `3`? Why does 4 result in 2,3 being set/toggled, but 5 sets/toggles 5 and 6? Are values set to 1, or toggled between 0 and 1 and vice versa? It's very unclear what the logic is you're applying.

Comment: It was just for demonstration purposes, but true!

Comment: True for the indexes, edited, i just typoed

Comment: I still don't understand why index 4 toggles the two indices *before* it, while f toggles the two indices *after* it. It's also still unclear indices are toggled, or just set to 1 (even if already 1).

Comment: I don't see why 5 actually indices a switch: element 5 is zero, the first index after the 4th is the 10th.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nils' answer seems good. Here is an alternative using NumPy only:

```
import numpy as np

def dilate(ar, amount):
    # Convolve with a kernel as big as the dilation scope
    dil = np.convolve(np.abs(ar), np.ones(2 * amount + 1), mode='same')
    # Crop in case the convolution kernel was bigger than array
    dil = dil[-len(ar):]
    # Take non-zero and convert to input type
    return (dil != 0).astype(ar.dtype)

# Test
inp = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0])
print(inp)
print(dilate(inp, 2))
```

Output:

```
[0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0]
```

Answer (score 3):

What you want is called "[binary dilation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_dilation.html)" and is contained in `scipy.ndimage`:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage

input = np.array([0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0], dtype=bool)
out = scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_dilation(input, iterations=2).astype(int)
# array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Another numpy solution :

```
def dilatation(seed,shift):
out=seed.copy()
for sh in range(1,shift+1):
    out[sh:] |= seed[:-sh]
for sh in range(-shift,0):
    out[:sh] |= seed[-sh:]
return out
```

Example (shift = 2) :

```
in : [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]
out: [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1]
```